# qsort mulit criteria sort condition in c

Tags: c

Context: [String array Sorting C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315932/string-array-sorting-c?rq=1) and [qsort with function comparator different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661671/qsort-with-function-comparator-different)

Full code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jPd6hezds).

```
char *str[ROWS][COLS] = {{"Russia", "Boxing", "Mens", "Gold"},
                {"America", "Cycling", "Mens", "Gold"},
                {"New Zealand", "Swimming", "Womens", "Silver"},
                {"India", "Badminton", "Mens", "Bronze"}};

 qsort(str,ROWS,sizeof(*str),(compare_rows));

static int compare_rows(const void * a,
  const void * b) {
  const int sort_colmn = 0;
  char * x1 = ((char ** ) a)[sort_colmn];
  char * x2 = ((char ** ) b)[sort_colmn];

  if (x2 == "India") return 1;

  if (x1 > x2 && x2 != "India") return 1;
  else if (x1 == x2) return 0;
  else return -1;

}
```

I'm trying to replicate the following SQL sort:

```
select * from (values('Russia'),('America'),('New Zealand'),('India')) cte(a) 
order by a='India' desc, a asc;
```

Desired order:

```
+-------------+
|      a      |
+-------------+
| India       |
| America     |
| New Zealand |
| Russia      |
+-------------+
```

Comment: I think you may be stuck rolling your own function for that. Try reading up on popular sorting methods, like bubble sort.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `compare_rows` function, you are attempting to compare strings by comparing their *addresses*. You can't do that.

For example, the comparison `x2 == "India"` is unlikely to be true, unless `x2` points to a 'merged' value of the string literal on the RHS of that comparison. Similar conditions exist for your other pointer comparisons.

To compare the strings pointed to by the given `char*` operands, you need to call the `strcmp` function:

```c
static int compare_rows(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const int sort_colmn = 0;
    // Note the added use of `const` for the pointers and casts ...
    const char* x1 = ((char*const*)a)[sort_colmn];
    const char* x2 = ((char*const*)b)[sort_colmn];

    if (strcmp(x1, "India") == 0) return -1; // Need to also add this test!
    if (strcmp(x2, "India") == 0) return 1;

    if (strcmp(x1, x2) > 0) return 1; // Comparing x2 to "India" here is redundant
    else if (strcmp(x1, x2) == 0) return 0;
    else return -1;
//  A much simpler way to encode the above three lines is just:
//  return strcmp(x1, x2);
}
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, indeed - well spotted! I have added the necessary extra check. The old answer worked 'by accident' on the data given in the OP's post.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2D array `str` is a contiguous collection of (16) memory addresses, each 'ptr' being independent of the other... `qsort` operates in chunks, be that integers, pointers or structs.

To use `qsort` clearly, first bind your 4 'columns' together into single chunks:

```
typedef struct {
    char *nation;
    char *sport;
    char *gender;
    char *medal;
} res_t;

res_t results[] = {
    {"Russia", "Boxing", "Mens", "Gold"},
    {"America", "Cycling", "Mens", "Gold"},
    {"New Zealand", "Swimming", "Womens", "Silver"},
    {"India", "Badminton", "Mens", "Bronze"}
};
```

Now, `results` is an array of 4 structs. Now, you can invoke `qsort()`.

```
qsort( results, sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0]), sizeof( results[0] ), compare );
```

`sizeof( results[0] )` is the size of one element, and
`sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0])` is the (compiler calculated) number of elements ('rows').

Your special-purpose comparison function can be made much simpler (and effective)...

```
static int compare( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    res_t *p1 = (res_t *)a;
    res_t *p2 = (res_t *)b;

    char *alwaysFirst = "India";
    if( strcmp( p1->nation, alwaysFirst ) == 0 ) return -1;
    if( strcmp( p2->nation, alwaysFirst ) == 0 ) return  1;

    return strcmp( p1->nation, p2->nation );
}
```